# Gödel's incompleteness theorem applys to ZFC theory

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

When I assume ZFC's consistency, it is impossible to prove ZFC's consistency in itself from Gödel's incompleteness theorem 2. 
If ZFC's consistency have done, its proof need to be done in stronger system(ZFC's axioms can be proved in it) than ZFC.
If this stronger system's consistency assumed to be consistency,its consistency can not be done in itself,be done in stronger System than it. 
Is it correct?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but the incompleteness theorem says that no consistent theory can prove its own consistency. So if we assume $ZFC$ is consistent we cannot prove that it is within $ZFC$ itself, another system would be required

Comment: You should try to edit your titles (including that of your previous question), avoiding using only noun phrases, so that they can be more tidy and informative.

Comment: @leibnewtz thank you for comment. Another system what you r saying, need to assumpt its consistent. In that case,this another system's consistent can not be done in this system itself.

Comment: @tarou Yup the theorem would apply to that theory as well

Comment: @Vim thank you for comment , i edit

Comment: @tarou you welcome. Enjoy yourself on MSE.

Comment: @leibnewtz That's not correct. As far as we know, there may very well be a theory extending $\operatorname{ZFC}$ proving its own consistency. We know, however, that this theory cannot be both consistent and recursively enumerable.

Comment: @Stefan recursively enumerable means we can not detect formula in System is whether axiom or not in finite step?

Comment: This system can not be applicable incompleteness theorem anymore ?

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the correction! I see I missed the subtlety there

Comment: @tarou Recursively enumerable means that there is a turing machine (which is essentially a computer with infinite memory, but a finite program) that can list all the formulae (well, their Gödel numbers) of the given theory. So Gödel's 2nd incompleteness theorem does not state that there are no reasonable (set) theories that prove their own consistency, but rather that any such theory must be pretty complicated when coded into a subset of the natural numbers. And that is - from a modern point of view - not that surprising (thinking of sharps and their 'potency').

Comment: @thank you for your comment. I udnerstand recursively enumerable so Gödel's 2nd incompleteness theorem can state it.